# Appending one vector to another vector

Tags: c++

I want to append a vector to another one, dynamically, so that I can build up a matrix, `x`.

```
int main()
{
    vector< vector<float> > x;
    vector<float> y = {1, 2, 3};
    x.insert(x.end(), y.begin(), y.end()) ;

    return 0;
}
```

But this gives me an error:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:340: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::vector<float>' and 'float')
        *__result = *__first;
                  ^
```

Any ideas?

Comment: My idea is that you should pick another overload of [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) to use.

Comment: Use `x.push_back(std::move(y))`

Comment: You are not appending a vector to vector. You are trying to append a vector to vector of vectors.

Comment: My idea is, that for a matrix vector of vector is a bad idea. Use a vector of size n*m. Wrap it in a class with `operator()(int row, int col)` or find an existing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Any ideas?

You are trying to add `float`s to a `vector<vector<float>>`. That's the problem.

If you change `x` to

```
vector<float> x;
```

the other line will work.

If you keep `x` as is, you can add `y` as an element of `x` with:

```
x.push_back(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<vector<float>> x;
vector<float> y = {1, 2, 3};
x.push_back(y);
```

`x.insert(x.end(), y.begin(), y.end());` attempts to insert `float`s into a `vector<vector<float>>`.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
x.push_back(y);
```

Answer (score 0):

With  `x.insert(x.end(), y.begin(), y.end())`, you are inserting `float` values where `vector<float>`-objects are expected.

If it is about initializing a 2D-vector with particular values for the rows, you could simply use a different constructor:

```
int main()
{
    vector<float> y = {1, 2, 3};  // row template object
    vector<vector<float>> x(10,y); // 2d vector with ten rows, each being a copy of row template y

    for (auto r : x) {
        for (auto c : r) {
            cout << c << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```